# Is there a performance impact for using code blocks in Java?

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I'm starting to play with OpenGL from Java, and I'm encountering a situation where I need to put a lot of code between many glBegin() and glEnd() calls, and would like for the code to be be auto formatted such that it is easy to see at a glance which code belongs to which glBegin/glEnd.

To accomplish this, I have been using an anonymous code block, like this:

```
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
{
   glVertex2f(100, 100);
   glVertex2f(100+200, 100);
   glVertex2f(100+200, 100+200);
   glVertex2f(100, 100+200);
}
glEnd();
```

My question is: are there any performance concerns, even if extremely minor, for using code blocks in this manner? Or is it identical to not using the code blocks at all once the program is compiled?

Comment: If you're worried about performance you should really be using modern OpenGL techniques. The performance benefit of using VBOs (OpenGL 1.5+) is going to be orders of magnitude greater than your attempts at optimizing everything around immediate mode rendering.

Comment: One thing to consider may be that anyone who reads your code may be confused at why those calls are in a different scope.

Comment: Actually I used blocks like that quite often.  It's a little to do with scope, but more to do with readability.  Well, I find it easier to read, I don't know about my colleagues :-).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There should be no cost for using blocks like this.  Blocks are a syntactic feature of the language used for scoping purposes and have no associated runtime functionality.  Looking at compiled bytecode executed by the JVM, there's no way to tell what the scoping rules of a function are, and so the JVM should give the same performance with and without the blocks.

Feel free to do this if you think it's easier to read.  In fact, that should almost always be your priority, unless you have a reason to suspect otherwise.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Actually I'm pretty sure there's not even a hard way to do this, since the existence of a block has absolutely no consequence to the semantics of the java program or changes any rules (in java it's illegal for variables declared in blocks to shadow local variables, so we can't have two different variables `x` for example)

Comment: @Voo- You could potentially do something with the symbols in the class file if you had declared the same variable in multiple scopes, though in general I agree.

Comment: How would you do that? I wasn't sure first too, so I checked and  `{int x; { char x;} }` gives a compile error. So we can't shadow local variables in an inner block, which I think is the only thing that could change semantics (or at least the code) in languages that allowed such a thing.

Comment: @Voo- Ah yes, I forgot that you can't do that in Java.  In that case I'm pretty sure it's impossible. :-)

Comment: Yeah I also had to try it out - actually I was pretty sure too that it would work and wanted to present it as a case where the extra scope had some effect ;)

Answer (score 5):

Those countless calls to glVertex impact your performance much more than anything else. That should be your real concern. Look into vertex arrays and vertex buffer objects for a *real* performance boost. Also your code will look nicer.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not going to declare variables local to the blocks, then don't use local blocks at all. You gain nothing by doing so, other than the very real possibility of causing confusion in the people that has to read and maintain your code, including yourself.

Local blocks are useful for declaring short-lived objects inside a method, objects that only remain in scope for the duration of the block. Even so, nothing guarantees you that they'll get garbage collected before the method ends.

Using local blocks as a performance optimization is moot, you're better off profiling your application and tuning the parts proven to be slow, instead of performing micro-optimizations such as this that will end up making the code harder to read and maintain.

Using local blocks for improving readability, well, it's debatable but it creates the possibility of opening a can of worms regarding scoping problems for the code being executed inside the block, possibly generating some very hard-to-find bugs.

For readability's sake, why not a couple of well-placed comments before and after each `glBegin()` and `glEnd()`?

Comment: Have you written some OpenGL code? (if not, you may not be aware of the usual structure of *old* openGL code) While I agree in general, when I wrote c++ OpenGL code I also indented `glBegin/End` and have seen lots of similar code. It just helps to highlight the structure - otherwise it can get pretty confusing and comments don't help. Also in Java it's impossible to change the semantic meaning of code by introducing additional local scopes (afaics) so I don't think it'll confuse anyone.